# SQL Dynamically Update from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, tableau-api

I'm new to SQL so I'm not even sure this is possible.

Is there a way to have SQL monitor a file on a network and if an excel file is dropped in there have it automatically clear any existing data and read in the excel file?

I have a Tableau dashboard that is updated a number of times a year. I need the dashboard to only reflect the latest data. Right now I have it reading from a csv and am manually reloading the data. I would love for this all to be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a language to access databases - with the correct connectors (depending on operating system) you can use SQL to extract data from an Excel spreadsheet. It could not be used to monitor a folder & check for existence of a file - typically you would use another language (eg C#) for this & also use that language to invoke the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could automate your data ingest process for Tableau.

One option is to first create an extract from your data source and then publish the data source to Tableau server. Then, making sure your workbook references the published data source, republish the workbook. Now you will be able to publish either the workbook or the data independently.

Then when you get new data, you need to refresh the extract based on the new CSV file. One way to do that on a Windows machine is to use the tableau refresh extract command utility.

See the data extract section of the Tableau [online help](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/help.htm#extracting_TDE.html)

On mac or linux, you can use the the data extract API from a script to refresh the extract since the utility isn't shipped for those platforms currently.

Or you can have the Tableau Server trigger the refresh on a schedule if that makes sense, assuming the CSV file has a standard network location that is visible to the server.

Alternatively, you could stand up a database and load your data into it, but if Tableau is your only client of the data, then the data extracts are probably the simplest approach.